# Hover effects not working for divs in 100vh tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm not sure why but the hover effect I'm going for isn't working for anything in the entire vh but starts working after I scroll down to the content below.

Anyone know why?

```
const DisplateDisplay = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const displates = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.displate.displates);

  let content = [];
  if (displates.length === 0) {
    content.push(<div>Loading...</div>);
  } else {
    displates.map((displate) => {
      content.push(
        <div
          className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center h-[300px] overflow-hidden"
          key={displate.id}
        >
          <label htmlFor="my-modal" key={displate.id}>
            <Image
              height={300}
              width={250}
              className="rounded-md hover:scale-125 duration-300 transition cursor-pointer"
              alt={displate.title || ""}
              src={`/images/${displate.category}/${displate.img}.jpg`}
              style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
              onClick={() => dispatch(setCurrentDisplate(displate))}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full lg:max-w-[1200px] xl:max-w-[1500px] md:max-w-[900px] sm:max-w-[700px] h-full grid lg:grid-cols-4 md:grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-10 px-auto -z-50">
      {content}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by "100vh tailwind"? I do not see 100vh mentioned in your code sample.

Comment: Whatever I see without scrolling, has no animation enabled. So everything in my 100vh is unresponsive, even the top half of some of the divs are unresponsive, but the bottom half are. It's super weird